# Returning local CassStatement pointer from function

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Cassandra's C++ driver and I have a doubt regarding some of the functions that I have used in my program where I've got functions like this:

```
    CassStatement* func()
    {
    /* Code */

    CassStatement* l_stmt= cass_prepared_bind(cass_future_get_prepared(l_future));
    //l_future is of type CassFuture* used in the 'Code' section

    return(l_stmt);
    }
```

Since l_stmt is a local variable, I'm slightly confused and want to make sure that I'm not doing any illegal memory access here. For e.g. in my main program, if I'm doing

```
CassStatement* x=func();
```

then, is it fine? I hope it's fine because I think that although l_stmt inside func is a local variable(on stack), but the address to which it is pointing will be on heap(returned by cass_prepared_bind()) and hence this should be fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I hope it's fine because I think that although l_stmt inside func is a local variable(on stack), but the address to which it is pointing will be on heap(returned by cass_prepared_bind()) and hence this should be fine!

This is correct. According to the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.5/api/struct.CassPrepared/):

> [`cass_prepared_bind`] Returns a bound statement that must be freed.

You therefore have to free the statement yourself using `cass_prepared_free`.